# Constant values in Rust generics

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

Does Rust language support constant values in generic code similar to c++ way? Seems that the language [overview](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#generics) doesn't advertise it. Parameterizing types with constants in C++ allows to create objects with preallocated buffers of different size depending on client's needs (types like stlsoft::[auto_buffer](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classstlsoft_1_1auto__buffer.html)).
If not, then what is the best practices to implement similar designs in Rust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not supported in a type-safe way. We would need type-level numeric literals, like GHC recently added, for that.

However, you can use Rust macros. With a macro you can create "templates" that are parameterized over arbitrary expressions, including constants, which would allow you to do what you want here. Note that you may find bugs and limitations in the macro system if you try this at the moment.

Comment: Macros seems like the aliens comparing to core language. Is there a room left for compile time expressions to be the ordinary parameters of the function in the Rust future?

Comment: I wish to parametrize a type over a function. Doing so with macros would require respecification of the function at most call sites. Alternately, I can "store" the function as a "value" in many different places within the structure to make it accessible. So parametrization over values would be really nice!

Comment: The solution to my problem is not to parametrize over a function but to do so over a type (probably an empty struct) implementing a certain trait. In theory at least; I or the compiler is having problems with the complexity of it.